# Simplify Multiple Join SQL Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i have select statment query with join statment, which I use to get value from joining the table

here's my Select query:

```
select 
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p1.Value3 end as fix1,
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p2.Value3 end as fix2,
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p3.Value3 end as fix3,
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p4.Value3 end as fix4,
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p5.Value3 end as fix5,
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p6.Value3 end as fix6
from tc t
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p1 on p1.Value2 = t.FIX 
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p2 on p2.Value2 = t.FIX1
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p3 on p3.Value2 = t.FIX2
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p4 on p4.Value2 = t.FIX3
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p5 on p5.Value2 = t.FIX4
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p6 on p6.Value2 = t.FIX5
where CUST_ACCT ='10053996'
```

I thought its to complicated , so I change my code like this :

```
select 
fix +' '+(select Value3 from Parameter where ParamType = 'fix' and Value2 = fix) as fix,
FIX1 +' '+(select Value3 from Parameter where ParamType = 'fix' and Value2 = FIX1) as FIX1,
FIX2 +' '+(select Value3 from Parameter where ParamType = 'fix' and Value2 = FIX2) as FIX2,
FIX3 +' '+(select Value3 from Parameter where ParamType = 'fix' and Value2 = FIX3) as FIX3,
FIX4 +' '+(select Value3 from Parameter where ParamType = 'fix' and Value2 = FIX4) as FIX4,
FIX5 +' '+(select Value3 from Parameter where ParamType = 'fix' and Value2 = FIX5) as FIX5
from tc where CUST_ACCT ='10053996'
```

is it possible to simplify my code ? or if I wanna do something like this I should Create select statment like that?

Comment: How bout you try to explain what you are trying to achieve also with the query

Comment: actually I want simplier and effective code , and also I want to avoid error from subquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about such solution?

```
SELECT /*extra fields from tc ==>>*/ x, y /*<<==*/
    , FIX, FIX1, FIX2, FIX3, FIX4, FIX5
FROM (
    SELECT fields, P.Value3, /*extra fields from tc ==>>*/ x, y /*<<==*/
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM tc
        WHERE CUST_ACCT ='10053996'
    ) T
    UNPIVOT (
        unpvt FOR fields in (FIX,FIX1,FIX2,FIX3,FIX4,FIX5)
    ) UPV
    LEFT JOIN Parameter P ON P.paramtype='fix' AND P.Value2 = UPV.unpvt
) T
PIVOT (
    MIN(Value3) FOR fields in (FIX,FIX1,FIX2,FIX3,FIX4,FIX5)
) AS PV
```

Comment: Just curious, how display all TC field by this code? unfamilliar with pivot unpivot things

Comment: Oh got it, so we should declare all field first, and call them back

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `Case` Statement with `IsNull(expression, valueIfNull)` in your first statement.

i have select statment query with join statment, which I use to get value from joining the table

here's my Select query:

```
select 
IsNull(p1.Value2 ,p1.Value3) as fix1,
IsNull(p1.Value2 ,p1.Value3) as fix2,
IsNull(p1.Value2 ,p1.Value3) as fix3,
IsNull(p1.Value2 ,p1.Value3) as fix4,
IsNull(p1.Value2 ,p1.Value3) as fix5,
IsNull(p1.Value2 ,p1.Value3) as fix6,
from tc t
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p1 on p1.Value2 = t.FIX 
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p2 on p2.Value2 = t.FIX1
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p3 on p3.Value2 = t.FIX2
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p4 on p4.Value2 = t.FIX3
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p5 on p5.Value2 = t.FIX4
left join (select * from  Parameter where paramtype='fix') as p6 on p6.Value2 = t.FIX5
where CUST_ACCT ='10053996'
```

Comment: aha, it's look more simplier, but is it still need 6 left join statement?

Comment: Yah, But join is better than sub query. A sub query in select statement is executed for each row where as join query executes for ones

Comment: yes, I've tried some scenarios and I found that subquery likely to get error because if it's found more than 1 value it'll throw an error

Comment: `case when p1.Value2 is not null then p1.Value3 end` and `IsNull(p1.Value2, p1.Value3)` give totally different results. In second case you will get `p1.Value3` if `p1.Value2 is null`, when in first case we have opposite conditions. Moreover, first clause will never return `p1.Value2` but the second one will.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't need to join the same table several times. Here is the simple trick to avoid it:

```
select 
case when pt.f = 1 then pt.Value3 end as fix1,
case when pt.f2 = 1 then pt.Value3 end as fix2,
... 
from tc
left join (select 
      CASE WHEN p.Value2 = t.FIX THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS f, 
      CASE WHEN p.Value2 = t.FIX1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS f1, 
      CASE WHEN p.Value2 = t.FIX2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS f2, 
      CASE WHEN p.Value2 = t.FIX3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS f3, 
      CASE WHEN p.Value2 = t.FIX4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS f4, 
      CASE WHEN p.Value2 = t.FIX5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS f5
    from  Parameter AS p where paramtype = 'fix') AS pt
    ON pt.Value2 IN (tc.FIX, tc.FIX2, tc.FIX3, tc.FIX4, tc.FIX5)
where CUST_ACCT ='10053996'
```

Probably you can simplify `JOIN`-conditions according to you concrete situation. The idea is to introduce parameters instead of multiple joins.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
select
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p1.Value3 end as fix1,
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p2.Value3 end as fix2, 
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p3.Value3 end as fix3, 
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p4.Value3 end as fix4, 
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p5.Value3 end as fix5, 
case when p1.Value2 is not null then p6.Value3 end as fix6 
from tc t 
left join Parameter as p1 
on p1.Value2 = t.FIX  AND p1.paramtype='fix'  
left join Parameter as p2 
on p2.Value2 = t.FIX1 AND p2.paramtype='fix'  
left join Parameter as p3
on p3.Value2 = t.FIX2 AND p3.paramtype='fix' 
left join Parameter as p4
on p4.Value2 = t.FIX3 AND p4.paramtype='fix' 
left join Parameter as p5
on p5.Value2 = t.FIX4 AND p5.paramtype='fix' 
left join Parameter as p6
on p6.Value2 = t.FIX5 AND p6.paramtype='fix' 
where CUST_ACCT ='10053996'
```